# Dell Venue 8 pro's bios freezes when inserted flashdrive

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, bios, dell-venue

My dell venue 8 pro windows tablet was not booting so i wanted to clean install windows 10 (tablet has only 1 port that is micro usb and no other port).

When i inserted bootable flash drive whole bios freezes, and im unable to proceed further by searching online i got to know it happens if usb drivers is currupt. But if i connect bluetooth mouse through usb its working fine, only data storing devices like pendrives, sd cards are not working through that port.

So, is there any solution for this so tgat i can reinstall windows 10...??

Comment: This tablet is probably about 9 years old, so there's not much point in investing in it.